# Android ImageAdapter using Volley from JSON

Tags: android, image, android-volley, gallery, android-glide

I am trying to create a gallery app for Android and I am using Volley and Glide.

I have an ImageAdapter class, which looks like this

```
import android.content.Context;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.BaseAdapter;
import android.widget.GridView;

import android.widget.ImageView;

import com.bumptech.glide.Glide;

public class ImageAdapter extends BaseAdapter {
private Context CTX;
private Integer image_id[] = {R.mipmap.sample_0,
        R.mipmap.sample_1, R.mipmap.sample_2,
        R.mipmap.sample_3,
        R.mipmap.sample_4,
        R.mipmap.sample_5,
        R.mipmap.sample_6,
        R.mipmap.sample_7
};

public ImageAdapter(Context CTX) {
    this.CTX = CTX;
}

@Override
public int getCount() {

    return image_id.length;
}

@Override
public Object getItem(int arg0) {
    return null;
}

@Override
public long getItemId(int arg0) {
    return 0;
}

@Override
public View getView(int arg0, View arg1, ViewGroup arg2) {
    ImageView img;

    if (arg1 == null) {
        img = new ImageView(CTX);
        img.setLayoutParams(new GridView.LayoutParams(200, 200));
        img.setScaleType(ImageView.ScaleType.CENTER_CROP);
        img.setPadding(8, 8, 8, 8);

    } else {
        img = (ImageView) arg1;
    }

    Glide.with(CTX)
            .load(image_id[arg0])
            .placeholder(R.mipmap.warning)
            .centerCrop()
            .crossFade()
            .into(img);


    return img;

  }
}
```

Right now I am passing to the adapter images from the image_id array, but in the MainActivity I am making a volley request which gets me some images(urls) from my server, which I store in a String array.

How can I pass that array of String URLs to the ImageAdapter class?

Answer (score 1):

pass `ArrayList` of images to the adapter in the constructor like

```
private Context cxt;
private ArrayList<String> images;
public ImageAdapter(Context cxt,ArrayList<String> images){
  this.cxt = cxt;
  this.images = images;
}

@override 
public void getCount(){
    return images == null ? 0 : images.size();
}
```

initially you can pass an empty `arraylist` and after loading data from volley updated the `arraylist` and call `adapter.notifyDataSetChanged()`

and in your getview you can access the image from the arraylist using position

Answer (score 0):

Just make some modification in Adapter:

```
import android.content.Context;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.BaseAdapter;
import android.widget.GridView;

import android.widget.ImageView;

import com.bumptech.glide.Glide;

public class ImageAdapter extends BaseAdapter {
    private Context CTX;
    private int image_id[] = {R.mipmap.sample_0,
            R.mipmap.sample_1, R.mipmap.sample_2,
            R.mipmap.sample_3,
            R.mipmap.sample_4,
            R.mipmap.sample_5,
            R.mipmap.sample_6,
            R.mipmap.sample_7
    };

    private String image_urls[];

    public ImageAdapter(Context CTX) {
        this.CTX = CTX;
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        if (image_urls != null && image_urls.length > 0) return image_urls.length;
        return image_id.length;
    }

    public void updateData(String[] urls) {
        this.image_urls = urls;
        this.notifyDataSetChanged();
    }

    @Override
    public Object getItem(int arg0) {
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public long getItemId(int arg0) {
        return 0;
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int arg0, View arg1, ViewGroup arg2) {
        ImageView img;

        if (arg1 == null) {
            img = new ImageView(CTX);
            img.setLayoutParams(new GridView.LayoutParams(200, 200));
            img.setScaleType(ImageView.ScaleType.CENTER_CROP);
            img.setPadding(8, 8, 8, 8);

        } else {
            img = (ImageView) arg1;
        }

        if (image_urls != null && image_urls.length > arg0) {
            Glide.with(CTX)
                    .load(image_urls[arg0])
                    .placeholder(R.mipmap.warning)
                    .centerCrop()
                    .crossFade()
                    .into(img);
        } else {
            Glide.with(CTX)
                    .load(image_id[arg0])
                    .placeholder(R.mipmap.warning)
                    .centerCrop()
                    .crossFade()
                    .into(img);
        }

        return img;
      }
    }
}
```

And when Volley returns successful:

```
yourAdapter.updateData(yourStringUrlArray);
```